# WebClient and StreamReader Class in build for Windows Store - Build Errors in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, hololens

I am developing an app for hololens using Unity in which I download a CSV from an API, then parse it etc. I found out that you cannot use the `WebClient` class to download the CSV and the `StreamReader` class to parse the CSV if you are building a Windows Store Application (WSA). I have been able to replace the WebClient by using the `WWW` class which is supported. I am trying to use this code to replicate what I was doing in  StreamReader but it isn't working so well:

```
var Folder =      Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var sp500 = @"..\Hololens\Assets\FinanceData\MarketTickers\";
Folder = await Folder.GetFolderAsync(sp500);

// acquire file 
var _File = await Folder.GetFileAsync("sp500.csv");

// read content
var _ReadThis = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);
```

Here is the complete code. I reviewed the Platform dependent compilation page (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) and added preprocessor directives so that I could also run the scripts in unity (within the editor) since the WebClient and StreamReader are supported and work fine in the unity editor. Any suggestions?

```
#if !UNITY_WSA_10_0
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var csvLine = reader.ReadLine();
                var firstCommaIndex = csvLine.IndexOf(",");
                var stock = csvLine.Substring(0, firstCommaIndex);

               // In case there are symbols in the stock names that would not be recognized by Yahoo API
                if (!tickers.Contains(stock) && !stock.Contains('/'))
                {
                    tickers.Add(stock);
                }
            }
         }
#else
        var Folder =      Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        var sp500 = @"..\Hololens\Assets\FinanceData\MarketTickers\";
        Folder = await Folder.GetFolderAsync(sp500);

        // acquire file 
        var _File = await Folder.GetFileAsync("sp500.csv");

        // read content
        var _ReadThis = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);
#endif
```

The errors I am getting when building for WSA Universal 10 SDK:

```
Assets/Scripts/FinanceFunctions.cs(59,33): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `Folder'
Assets/Scripts/FinanceFunctions.cs(65,41): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `Windows'
Assets\Scripts\FinanceFunctions.cs(65,29): error CS4032: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<string>'.
```

Comment: Didn't they renamed "Folder" into "StorageFolder" in UWP 10? I think your method calls are depreciate for the current UWP SDK.

Comment: If you want to get file in the prj that you can use AppData.Current.LoacalFolder and you should not use `sp500 ` as url to get the file .

Comment: Even if you compile this code, you can't read outside of your installed location (`"..\"` tries to escape out of your directory structure). Also you need to have an `async` method if you want to use `await` - this isn't the entire code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you want is to download a .csv and parse it without using WebClient or StreamReader.

For parsing I would use something like this [CSVReader](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CSVReader)

And the code would be something like this called by a MonoBehaviour's StartCoroutine():

```
public IEnumerator GetCSVCoroutine(System.Action<string[,]> OnFinished)
{
    var downloader = new WWW("csvurl.com/csvfile.csv");
    yield return downloader;
    var fileText = downloader.text;
    string[,] csvGrid = CSVReader.SplitCsvGrid(fileText);
    OnFinished(csvGrid);
}
```

Also, instead of WWW you could also use [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html)

I hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use StreamReader Unity3D gives you the chance of using a [WinRTLegacy](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-missingtypes.html) namespace. This should contain a legacy version of `System.IO.StreamReader`.

The best way of implementing that is to add this in your **using** section

```
#if NETFX_CORE
using StreamReader = WinRTLegacy.IO.StreamReader;
#else
using StreamReader = System.IO.StreamReader;
#endif
```

You can then go on using it as you always have.

The `#if NETFX_CORE` is absolutely necessary because none of the .NET Core based namespaces are currently available in the editor.
This is a nuisance, because you can only test the code while building, as that is the only phase where the actual .NET Core APIs get involved.

---

EDIT:
I just realised you had a totally different problem.
Here's the correct solution for you:

```
#if NETFX_CORE
        public static string ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            var task = LoadFileAsync(filename);

            Task.WaitAll(task);

            return task.Result;
        }

        private static async Task<string> LoadFileAsync(string filename)
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);

            return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        }
#endif
```

Note that you cannot use this function in the editor, as some namespaces such as `Windows` e the `await` keyword are only available when compiled using .NET Core library, which is currently unavailable in the Unity Editor environment.

It might be better to have the same function use different implementations basing on whether you are on a UWP build or any other environment.